# ¿Cómo cambiar la visualización de un grafico en r markdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, r-markdown, plotly

tengo un problema ya que estoy haciendo un reporte en R markdown, y en la visualización de gráfico con ggplotly este se me encimado a comparación de la presentación de la ventana de Viewer, ¿alguien sabe como expandir mi gráfico en r markdown?

Gracias, anexo problema con el graph

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ajustar el aspecto de tu gráfica en el marco de un documento `rmarkdown`, mediante los atributos `fig.width` y `fig.height`, que son atributos que se configuran en la definición del "chunk", de esta forma:

````
```{r, fig.width=5, fig.height=5}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point()
```
````

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

````
```{r, fig.width=10, fig.height=5}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point()
```
````

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modificando el aspecto, más ancho que alto, seguramente corrijas la mayoría de los problemas con los textos, aún así, tienes algunas leyendas, tal vez demasiado largas, puedes probar achicarlas, o bien agregarles saltos de linea `\n` a cada texto.